# Permission denied while using 'Kaa-Node restart'

Tags: kaa

I am trying on an application and previously it worked and the data was able to be persisted into MongoDB. But recenntly , we had a change of router and thus we went ahead to regenerate SDK and etc but we still has the connection error.

Error :

```
2017/01/26 9:24:27 [WARNING] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:612] (-7) - Could not find next Bootstrap access point (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
2017/01/26 9:24:27 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:307] (-7) - Kaa TCP channel [0x929A2016] error notifying bootstrap manager on access point failure
2017/01/26 9:24:27 [ERROR] [kaa_client.c:240] (-7) - Failed to process OUT event for the client socket 3
```

And thus , we went ahead with troubleshooting where one of the staffs i emailed passed me a link for troubleshooting .

```
https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/Troubleshooting/
```

I followed already but i had an error where im stucked with writing 'kaa-node restart' to restart the node service.

Here are the commands for troubleshooting:

```
Connect to your Kaa Sandbox via ssh:
    $ ssh kaa@<YOUR-SANDBOX-IP>
    password: kaa
Stop the Kaa service:
    $ sudo service kaa-node stop
Clear the Kaa logs:
    $ sudo rm -rf /var/log/kaa/*
Start the Kaa service:
    $ sudo service kaa-node start
```

I typed 'sudo service kaa-node start'. it gave me:

```
kaa@kaa-sandbox.kaaproject.org:~$ sudo service kaa-node start
 * Starting Kaa Node daemon (kaa-node):
/bin/bash: /var/log/kaa/kaa-node-server.init.log: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the Kaa host on the Management page. Also, the Sandbox Web UI (the Management page) is able to restart all the necessary Kaa services on the Sandbox after the Kaa host change.

Please note that the Kaa host should match the PC host IP address accessible from the network your applications are running in.

Please try and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Still didnt work. But its fine , but i would like to ask if you know anything about ' log upload bucket error' ? @MrKoin